# Accessing function from inside of a subview controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a [walkthrough library written in swift](https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough), and I am trying to have the keyboard to be displayed only on a specific step in the walkthrough. If I add a textField to that specific view controller in the storyboard, and make it become the first responder, the keyboard is shown for all of the other view controllers as well. What I am trying to accomplish is when the user is on this specific page, I would like the keyboard to be present, and when they scroll away, for it to disappear with the swipe.

The library offers a function called `walkthroughPageDidChange`, however it’s on the master view controller where all the subview controllers are attached to. I can check if the pageNumber is the one I want it to be, however I am not sure how to accomplish accessing a function inside of one of the attached view controller pages.

I would like to access the keyboard controller with the following functions:

`KeyboardViewController.showKeyboard()` - becomeFirstResponser for textField
`keyboardViewController.hideKeyboard()` - resignFirstResponder for textField

```
if pageNumber == 2 {
  KeyboardViewController.showKeyboard()
}else{
  KeyboardViewController.hideKeyboard()
}
```

How would I accomplish this? How would I be able to access this function inside of another view controller?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep an array of your ViewControllers in the parent ViewController when you create them. So in your array you pick the right controller and call the function you want. I did not see the code where the viewcontrollers are stored in an array your link, but you can just add it where you create the VCs.